# GUI Program to send raw http requests in Windows?

Tags: http, tcp

As much as I love curl and wget, I want to be able to send HTTP requests and easily change the headers, target host, URI, etc. without having to type it in a CLI all the time. Are there any programs for Windows that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, you should give a look at the taper-data firefox plug-in:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/